# How to filter by key

Tags: json, jq

I have this sort of json:

```
[
    {
        "source": 
        {
            "file": "test",
            "baz": "now"
        }
    },
    {
        "source": {
            "dev": "foo"
        }
    },
    
    {
        "source": {
            "bar": "bar"
        }
    }
]
```

and I would like to get a list of all values for `file` or `dev`. So the expected outcome of the above should be: `["test", "foo"]`

I am stuck somewhere here:

```
.[].source | select(.file? or .dev?)
```

But that yield the complete objects. How to access only the attribute values than??

Comment: @RamChander No. No connection to ES6 in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can traverse to `.file` and `.dev` at once using `.source | .file, .dev` or `.source["file", "dev"]`, then filter out null values using `values` (not `?`).

```bash
map(.source | .file, .dev | values)
# or
map(.source["file", "dev"] | values)
```

```json
[
  "test",
  "foo"
]
```

Comment: That one is pretty tight.

Comment: This answer is my favorite because it is specific, compact and suits best to my use-case. But depending on the use-case and input, the other approaches given might work better.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: This approach could be rewritten for arbitrary depths using `..` as follows: `map(.. | objects.source | .file, .dev | values)`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `?` or other operators, using `getpath/1` is one option, where you can just filter paths and get their value

```
[ getpath(paths | select(.[-1] == "file" or .[-1] == "dev")) ]
```

Or even combine with another condition to check for `source` key, if you want to be completely sure i.e. `.[-2] == "source"`

Demo - https://jqplay.org/s/IddhVIbUenj

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `tostream` that will essentially descend to any depth and extract the values of the `"file"` or `"dev"` key.

```jq
[ tostream | select(.[1] and (.[0][-1] | IN("file", "dev"))) | .[1] ]
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/-O9PUezKfWs).

Comment: Even though that one is really cryptic I really like the idea of »descend to any depth«, but in my case that is not needed.